# Spatie backup using Artisan::call() unable to delete temp folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backup

Im able to create backup with files using
`Artisan::call('backup:run --only-files)` many times, but when it comes to
`Artisan::call('backup:run --only-db)` it can only do once. I noticed that the temp folder is not empty due to the saved `db.sql` has only read permissions. when I added manually a `write` permission, then the temp folder can be deleted.

There is no issue using a command line, only when I use `Artisan::call()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be some few things:

1 - Your file **db.sql** must be have the write permissions, not the temp folder, and this is should be done by the lib / code itself, doesn't matter if you do it manually since the file is dynamically created by the code.

2 - The lib / code probably is blocking you to do sequential backup since you already have a artisan job / command running, I created to here same stuff of my work when I'm uploading a large files of excel, you can do this job once, you cannot upload one after other.

I strong suggest to you take a look at the official website and documentation.

If I'm not mistake this is the website -> https://spatie.be/open-source

If i'm wrong please do correct me.

I hope that could help you out.

Comment: Not a direct answer but it made me realized things. Now it works :D, thanks mate

Comment: Nice dude, I'm glad that helped you out.